# range input disable does not work in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am disabling my range input however in chrome it shows it grayed out but it is still usable.

```
<input type="range" disabled min="0" max="100"/>
```

I would assume the above would not allow you to change its value.

Am I doing it wrong?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AgdJG/)

Relevant specification [Disabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1)

Comment: Sounds like a bug, you should report it.

Comment: @minitech It's too bad their reporting system is a giant black hole.

Comment: There is that. You could try a script that continuously resets the position if it's disabled, but that's a terrible hack. Sorry for not being much of a help :(

Comment: That input is properly disabled in Chrome 15.

Comment: Black hole? Please file bugs at http://new.crbug.com. (As mentioned, this is fixed in 15, so no need this time)

Comment: @Boris Referring to the wrench->tools->report an error option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Chrome bug report, guess just need to wait for version 15 as the commenters mentioned.

[Bug 54820](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=54820)

Answer (score 1):

I found a corny solution for chrome, because it doesn't seem like you can disable it from user input.  Put a div over it so a user cannot interact with it. Not pretty but works:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:5;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
    <input type="range" disbaled=True min="0" max="100" value="0"/><span id="v">100</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP included a jsFiddle, you should have tried it, you should have read the post. -1

Comment: Just to explain Matto, disabled can be used without a value however you can't set an attribute through javascript without a value, so people usually use disabled as the value. Regardless as my example shows, chrome DOES see that it is disabled, it just doesn't do anything about it other than change the color.

Comment: This is a nice hacky solution. I'd add a handler for the onfocus event, so if it's readonly it'll blur the input immediately. Otherwise if you tab into it, you can manipulate it with the keyboard arrows.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove all binded events of that specific scroll group to make that scroll disable like:

```
<div id="fieldset1">
<input type="range" disabled min="0" max="100" readonly="1"/>
</div>

<script>
 $(":range").rangeinput();
 $('#fieldset1 *').unbind(); // for all events
</script>
```

its works ..
no need to disable text field; beacause on form submission that field will not be posted ..

Answer (score 1):

My solution [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4EwU8/) (Works fine in default android browser)
html

```
<input id="range" type="range" value="10" min="0" max="30" step="10"/>
<button id="disableBtn">Disable</button>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('disableBtn').addEventListener('input', filter);
document.getElementById('disableBtn').addEventListener('click', disable);

function disable(){
    document.getElementById('range').disabled = !document.getElementById('range').disabled;
}

function filter(){
    if(document.getElementById('range').disabled){
        document.getElementById('range').value = document.getElementById('range').defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work.